# DevExpress SpinEdit cleared as soon as control loses focus

Tags: c#, .net, devexpress

I've got a DevExpress.XtraEditors.SpinEdit with a DateTime edit mask:

```
baseSpinEdit1.Properties.Mask.MaskType = MaskType.DateTime;
baseSpinEdit1.Properties.Mask.EditMask = "t";
baseSpinEdit1.Properties.EditFormat.FormatType = FormatType.DateTime;
baseSpinEdit1.Properties.EditFormat.FormatString = "t";
baseSpinEdit1.Properties.DisplayFormat.FormatType = FormatType.DateTime;
baseSpinEdit1.Properties.DisplayFormat.FormatString = "t";
baseSpinEdit1.Properties.Mask.UseMaskAsDisplayFormat = true
```

This works as expected while the control has focus, but as soon as another control gets focus it is cleared. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried to use TimeEdit with EditMask = "t"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [SpinEdit](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/clsDevExpressXtraEditorsSpinEdittopic) control is designed to work with numeric values only. If you want to work with DateTime, please use the [TimeEdit](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/clsDevExpressXtraEditorsTimeEdittopic) instead of SpinEdit.